# Control the axis' title label-color

Tags: python, altair

Struggling to set the color of my axis labels.

```
base = alt.Chart(xf.loc['2017':].reset_index(), title="trouble").encode(
    x='Date'
)

rigs = base.mark_line(color='blue').encode(
    alt.Y('Total Oil Rigs', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False),axis=alt.Axis( title='I should BLUE'))
)

prod = base.mark_line(color='green').encode(
    alt.Y('US Crude Production', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False),axis=alt.Axis( title='I should be GREEN'))
)

alt.layer(
    rigs,
    prod
).resolve_scale(
    y='independent'
).configure_axisLeft(labelColor='blue').configure_axisRight(labelColor='green')
```

I can set #2 and #3 using the `configure_axisLeft/Right()` functions,  but I cannot find a way to set color of the axis' title (#1, #4).  I don't see a option in the [altair.Axis](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Axis.html) documentation either.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `titleColor` configuration:

```
chart.configure_axisLeft(
  labelColor='blue'
  titleColor='blue'
).configure_axisRight(
  labelColor='green',
  titleColor='green'
)
```